# How can I display 3D-Models made in Paint3D with arcore in augmented reality

Tags: android-studio, fbx, 3d-modelling, gltf, sceneform

I want to create simple 3D-Models in Paint3D and display them in Augmented Reality with arCore using android. But whatever model format I use there are always problem/they are not working at all.

When I save the 3D-Model as .glb I can easily view it using any .glb/.gltf viewer and its working fine. I then converted it to .gltf and imported it in android studio with the Goole Sceneform Tools, but when displaying them in AR they are invisible.

When I save the 3D-Model as .fbx I am able to display them in AR but as they arent rectangular the space around the corners is filled up black.

I suspect that the problem is that the Sceneform Tools mostly are use with external ressources like .mtl and my .gltf have includes ressources, but I dont know of a way the extract them. So does anyone have any experience displaying 3D-Models created in Paint3D in Augmented Reality?

If not, are there any other easy programs to build 3D-Models out of pngs? Because in Paint3D you literally just drag in the pngs and  that most of the work already done.

Comment: Can ARCore use the GLB file directly?  (GLB is just the binary packed form of glTF).

Comment: Sadly the Sceneform Tool dont support it i think but I tried it with this converter (https://github.com/gdamoreira/google-ar-asset-converter) and got the same result as with the .gltf